# Filter for rows that have less than 4 NA's per condition

Tags: r, filter, missing-data

I have a large proteomics data set with 14 samples (columns) and 3000+ proteins (rows).  No information about which of the two conditions the samples belong to has been added.
About 50% of the data is NA. I would like to delete the rows that have 4 or more missing values per condition. I thought it might be possible with the `filter()` function. How could I specify the conditions of the columns and add code that specifies only those rows with 3 results per condition should be kept? I am sorry if this is a very basic question that has been asked and answered before, however i` have not been able to find the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `rowSums` to count the number of missing values in the row, and then you can use that to determine which rows you want to keep.

```r
x <- matrix(rnorm(1400), ncol = 14)
x[x < 0] <- NA

x2 <- x[rowSums(is.na(x)) < 4, ]
```

Comment: If I understand correctly ' ' 'x[rowSums(is.na(x)) < 4, ] ' ' ' is used to select all rows in which less than 4 NA's are missing? This would be a good option if I could add a part that adds the 2 conditions. So could I select only the columns for the first condition, then select those rows with less than 4 NA's. Then could I additionally select the columns for the second condition and select those rows with less than 4 NA's and then have one df with rows that have less than 4 NA's in each condition?

Comment: What does the part that adds the two conditions look like?  Is it another row of data, something in the column names, something else?

Comment: Nothing yet, all the columns have name, and I know which names correspond to which two of the condition. So could I select the names of  the columns from one condition and then select those rows with less than 4 NA's. And also select the names of the rows with the second condition and select those rows with less than 4 NA's? My goal is to have for each row at least 4 non na's per condition

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd do.  Suppose you have your condition 1 column names stored in a vector c1, then something like `x[rowSums(is.na(x[, colnames(x) %in% c1])) < 4, colnames(x) %in% c1] ` should return just the columns for condition 1 and just the rows where those columns have fewer than 4 NAs.

Comment: So now I'm trying to select al, rows and create a matrix Z in which for columns 9, 10,11,1,2,4,5 there are less than 3 NA's, and for columns 3,6,7,8,12,13,14 there are 7 NA's. I using this code               Z <- df[c(rowSums(is.na(df[, c(9:11,1,2,4,5)]) < 3)) & (rowSums(is.na(df[, c(6:8,12:14,3)]) == 7)),]    However, I don't get a good output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the c() around everything, and instead of having two parentheses after 3 and 7, you should have two before the inequality symbols to close out the rowSums calculation before checking whether its less than 3 or equal to 7. `Z <- df[(rowSums(is.na(df[, c(9:11,1,2,4,5)])) < 3) & (rowSums(is.na(df[, c(6:8,12:14,3)])) == 7),]`